# Joomla: Add extra fields to user activation email body

Tags: php, email, joomla

I am developing a joomla site, and upon registration joomla sends an email to user with an activation link. I want to change the content of that email. I have successfully created a language override for the email, but I also added some extra fields in the email.
I was wondering ow to map those fields values in the email. I have changed the user plugin file and the user model in the com_user component, but nothing works. Can anyone tell me where to change that. 
It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/how-to-add-extra-fields-to-the-activation-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in components/com_users/models/registration.php
at line 405 to 507
this lines are that you need to change

Comment: Please add the corresponding lines in your answer and show what need to be changed.